# Handle application error problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, global-asax

I am using MVC project and hase been logging the application errors in `Global.ascx`.

This is my code

```
protected void Application_Error(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            System.Exception exception = Context.Server.GetLastError();
            var stackTraceExcep = new StackTrace(exception, true); // create the stack trace
            var stackTrace = stackTraceExcep.GetFrames()         // get the frames
                          .Select(frame => new
                          {                   // get the info
                              FileName = frame.GetFileName(),
                              LineNumber = frame.GetFileLineNumber(),
                              ColumnNumber = frame.GetFileColumnNumber(),
                              Method = frame.GetMethod(),
                              Class = frame.GetMethod().DeclaringType,
                          }).FirstOrDefault();


            string FileName = stackTrace.FileName;
            string LineNumber = stackTrace.LineNumber.ToString();
            string ColumnNumber = stackTrace.ColumnNumber.ToString();
            string MethodName = stackTrace.Method.Name;
            string ClassName = stackTrace.Class.Name;
            int Errornumber = Convert.ToInt32(errorRepository.AddError(exception.Message, FileName, Convert.ToInt32(LineNumber), Convert.ToInt32(ColumnNumber), MethodName, ClassName));//This line helps to stores the error in my database.
            Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/Error/{0}/?errorNumber={1}", "App_Error", Server.UrlEncode(Errornumber.ToString())));//Pass the error number to a cantroller for show the error number(last inserted id) in view
            context.Server.ClearError();
        }
```

okay let me go to the problem here

The above code was working fine on my local computer . This code stores (`error path , error name ,error line number ,error column number, error method name, error class name .`) in the database.

Now, when I publish my project and deploy the publish version on the server (`Arvixe`) .

The code in my  application error method works fine for `class name method name and exception message` and stores this data in the Database, but the `error line number` and   `error column number`  are not stored in the database. I saw the database , It's stores nothing .

What is the problem ? Why the `error line number` and `error column name` are not stored when deployed to the web server(everything works fine on my local system) ?

I have some doubts

1) The project is a published version , So all the  project files(class,controllers,models,etc ( i think you know  that)) are converted to DLL , So I guess  `StackTrace` does not get the error line details ? Am I correct ? else tell me .

2)The server does not have visual studio . So i guess this is not working ? Am I correct  else tell me ?

Comment: When you publish your application it is compiled in Release mode and information about line numbers is no longer contained in the `StackTrace`.

Comment: I really don't mean to offend, but if possible, please get someone more familiar with english to help you write your question. This is extremely difficult to understand.

Comment: @tnw . Thanks for your edit . Sorry for my poor English

Comment: @DarinDimitrov . Okay thanks. Now what can i do ? shall i go publish to debug mode ?

Comment: No, you should not publish in Debug mode. You could include the .PDB files when deploying which contain this information.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the connection string is not set up properly. The Handle Application error happens when there's no way to connect to the database. Open your web.config file and add the connection string there.